# insert from RichTextBox into a doc file using OpenXml

Tags: c#, winforms, openxml

I want to insert what is writting in a richtextbox into a doc file footer, when i change **text1.Text = "Footer"** to **text1.Text = txtFoot.text**, an error appeared " **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form2.txtFoot'** ", and when i tried " **Text txt = txtFoot.text** ", another error appeared " **cannot convert string into documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.text** ", how can i fix this ?

```
static void GenerateFooterPartContent(FooterPart part)
    {
        Footer footer1 = new Footer() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
        footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
        ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" };

        paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

        Run run1 = new Run();
        Text text1 = new Text();
        text1.Text = "Footer"; 

        run1.Append(text1);

        paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
        paragraph1.Append(run1);

        footer1.Append(paragraph1);

        part.Footer = footer1;
    }
```

Comment: Is the whole document being generated dynamically or you're using some template doc and adding a footer in that?

Comment: @KetanRaiyani the document is being generated dynamically

Comment: Did the solution I provided work?

Comment: sorry, i totally forgot. It didn't work, instead, a wrote all the code inside the method in which i was calling **GenerateFooterPartContent()** and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`text1.Text` here is actually a `Wordprocessing.Text`, not a string object. In order to assign the text to it, you will have to do this-

```
text1.Text = new Text(txtFoot.text);
```